# Size a TextBlock to a Button that changes Width dynamically

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a `TextBlock` that's on top of a `Button` in a `Grid`. I'd like to have then displayed thus:

`"some very long text"  <-- text

   "that doesn't fit"     <-- text wrapped

   [my button text size]  <-- button`

However, what I've got is this:

`"some very long text that doesn't fit"  <-- text

                    [my button text size]  <-- button`

My issue is that the text in the `Button` is dynamically set through localized resource and therefore the width of the button changes dynamically.

The static solution that works for non-dynamic `Button` resize is:

```
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="5"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=requestDemoButton, Path=RenderSize.Width}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Resource.Text, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}"
                    />
                <Button 
                    x:Name="requestDemoButton"
                    Margin="5" 
                    Height="Auto" 
                    Width="Auto" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Content="{Binding Path=Resource.Button, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}" />
```

Ideas, anyone? I'm currently thinking of sticking a Behavior class to the `TextBlock` that listens for the `SizeChanged` event on the `Button`. I'd like to have a built-in solution if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's interested, here's how I've done in in a behaviour. 
I pass on `Height` or `Width` according to the property I want bound.

Here's the class:

```
public static class DynamicControlResizeBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Target", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(DynamicControlResizeBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnTargetSetCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PropertyName", typeof(string), typeof(DynamicControlResizeBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnPropertyNameSetCallback));


    public static string GetPropertyName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(PropertyNameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPropertyName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PropertyNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static FrameworkElement GetTarget(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (FrameworkElement)obj.GetValue(TargetProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTarget(DependencyObject obj, FrameworkElement value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TargetProperty, value);
    }

    private static void SynchronizeProperty(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        var target = GetTarget(dependencyObject);
        if (target != null)
        {
            var propertyName = GetPropertyName(dependencyObject);

            DependencyProperty dependencyToRead;
            DependencyProperty dependencyToWrite;
            if (string.Equals(propertyName, "Width", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                dependencyToRead = FrameworkElement.ActualWidthProperty;
                dependencyToWrite = FrameworkElement.WidthProperty;
            }
            else if (string.Equals(propertyName, "Height", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                dependencyToRead = FrameworkElement.ActualHeightProperty;
                dependencyToWrite = FrameworkElement.HeightProperty;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            var propertySize = (double)target.GetValue(dependencyToRead);
            dependencyObject.SetValue(dependencyToWrite, propertySize);
        }
    }

    private static void OnTargetSetCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oldElement = e.OldValue as FrameworkElement;
        if (oldElement != null)
        {
            oldElement.SizeChanged -= (o, s) => SynchronizeProperty(d);
        }

        var newElement = e.NewValue as FrameworkElement;
        if (newElement != null)
        {
            newElement.SizeChanged += (o, s) => SynchronizeProperty(d);
        }
    }

    private static void OnPropertyNameSetCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SynchronizeProperty(d);
    }
}
```

And here's how it's used:

```
            <TextBlock
                Behaviors:DynamicControlResizeBehavior.Target="{Binding ElementName=submitButton}"
                Behaviors:DynamicControlResizeBehavior.PropertyName="Width"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="5,20,5,5"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="{Binding Path=Resource.RequestDemoLoginText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}"
                />
            <Button 
                x:Name="submitButton"
                Margin="5" 
                Height="Auto" 
                Width="Auto" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Content="{Binding Path=Resource.RequestDemoLogin, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}" />
```

Hope that might help someone else.

Comment: Good but, must be used carefully ,If you bind target element to Higher level element Height is always bigger than own element you got Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) .With some checks it works well. thanks